# How do I add a submodule with an SSH URL without a private key

Tags: git

I have a git repo A on a private server accessible via SSH using password based authentication (no SSH keys). I would like to add a submodule to my repo to another repo B on the same server.

here is my .gitsubmodules

```
[submodule "B"]
    path = B
    url = ../B.git
```

However when i try to do a submodule update I get :

```
Cloning into '/A/B'...
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
vinz243@server: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
fatal: clone of 'vinz243@server:/repos/B' into submodule path '/A/B' failed
```

I have been banging my head against this one. Most of the other posts talk about SSH private keys or using HTTP(s) URL, but I do not want any of these

Comment: If you `ssh vinz243@server` does it ask for a password? This may not be a git issue. It could also be waiting for you to type `yes`.

Comment: @EncryptedWatermelon yes it does ask for a password and let me login. Running git clone also asks for my password (and it works). It seems really about the submodules